# Asserting that a parent component exists in angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I have a top level component `AppComponent` and in it's `template` property it renders the `<child>` element on the page. (`<child>` is another Angular component).

Do I need to tell the unit test to ignore the `<child>` element or declare it in some way for the test?

I'm not actually trying to test `<child>` in this test file, I will create a separate unit test file to validate it's functionality.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent, ChildComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<child></child>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent { }
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

describe('App', (() => {
  beforeEach(async() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ declarations: [AppComponent, ChildComponent] }).compileComponents();
  }));
  it('should work', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    // assert app.component exists
  });
});
```

When I run the unit test, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: This test module uses the component ChildComponent which is using a "templateUrl" or "styleUrls", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test. in /tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-3142O76A6m7KjQOD.js (line 3929)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that other units (`ChildComponent`) are involved in test. This error is caused by the fact that `ChildComponent` uses `templateUrl`, and such components may need to call `compileComponents` to compile them.

Since `AppComponent` has `template` and not `templateUrl`, this makes a test synchronous and makes `async` helper unnecessary, also eliminates the need to use `compileComponents`.

As explained in [the guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#compile-components),

> The TestBed.compileComponents method asynchronously compiles all the components configured in the testing module. In this example, the BannerComponent is the only component to compile. When compileComponents completes, the external templates and css files have been "inlined" and TestBed.createComponent can create new instances of BannerComponent synchronously.

Unit test presumes that only one unit is tested, while other units are ignored, stubbed or mocked. This allows to keep a test isolated.

Since undeclared components will result in error, they have to be stubbed:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    @Component({ selector: 'child', template: '' })
    class DummyChildComponent {}

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ declarations: [AppComponent, DummyChildComponent] });
  });
```

An alternative to dummy component is `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` or `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`, which aren't suitable in tests because any possible error output may be valuable. And [custom schema](http://[custom%20schema][2]) is more heavy-weight solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `ChildComponent` to your module:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ declarations: [AppComponent, ChildComponent] });
  });
```

Comment: I've added `ChildComponent` to `declarations` and then called `compileComponents()` but its not detecting that `compileComponents()` is being called