# Angular Unit Testing with Karma Jasmine : Test Imported librariries

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, devextreme

Am new on Angular unit testing .

I started by generating the basic unit test for each of my component : the test of the component creation :

**MyComponent.spec.ts**

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

To make that test works , as i notice , i should declare and imprts all my used libs and files.

in my case : i'm using **DevExtreme** UI Widgets in all my projet parts , i imported it globally:

**app.module.ts :** (last import)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from './../shared/shared.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomerModule } from './customer/customer.module';
import { ApplicationParametersComponent } from './superAdministrator/application-parameters/application-parameters.component';
import { InscriptionComponent } from './inscription/inscription.component';

import { DevExtremeModule } from 'devextreme-angular';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    ApplicationParametersComponent,
    InscriptionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    CustomerModule,
    DevExtremeModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

fo exaple in my component i'm using a **dataGrid** widget from the **DevExtremeModule**:

**MyComponent.ts :**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Response, Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Input, ContentChildren, ViewChild, QueryList} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpService} from './../../../shared/service';
import {SessionService} from './../../../shared/service';
import {Customer, TableState, StateCustomer} from './../../../model';
import {DxDataGridComponent} from 'devextreme-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-MyComponent',
  templateUrl: './MyComponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./MyComponent.component.css']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(DxDataGridComponent) grid: DxDataGridComponent;

  customersList: Customer[];
  error: string;
  StateCustomer = StateCustomer; 
  Customer = Customer; /
  private dataGridConfig: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpService,
              private sessionService: SessionService,
              private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.tableStateSave = this.tableStateSave.bind(this);

    const url = this.http.wsCustomer
      .concat('getAll/')
      .concat('0/')
      .concat('999999/')
      .concat('null/')
      .concat('null');
    this.http.get(url)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json().map((jsonItem) => Customer.parseJson(jsonItem)))
      .subscribe(
        (customers: Customer[]) => this.customersList = customers,
        (error: Response) => console.error(error)
      );

    // Récupération état grid
    const urlStateGrid = this.http.wsSession
      .concat('tableStateLoad/')
      .concat(TableState.convertIdStringTableToInt('customersTable')
        .toString());
    this.http.get(urlStateGrid, false)
      .map((result: Response) => JSON.parse(result.json()))
      .subscribe(
        (tableConfig: any) => {
          this.dataGridConfig = tableConfig;
          this.tableStateLoad = this.tableStateLoad.bind(this);
        }
      );
  }

  create(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/customer-detail']);
  }

  view(customer: Customer): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/customer-detail/'.concat(customer.id.toString())]);
  }

  delete(customer: Customer): void {
    const url = this.http.wsCustomer
      .concat('delete/')
      .concat(customer.id.toString())
      .concat('/')
      .concat(customer.version.toString()
      );

    this.http.delete(url).subscribe(
      this.customersList.splice(this.customersList.indexOf(customer), 1);
      () => null,
      (error: Response) => console.error(error)
    );
  }

  tableStateSave(gridState: object): void {

    this.saveState(gridState);
  }

  manualSave() {
    const detectedState = this.grid.instance.state();

    this.saveState(detectedState);
  }
  saveState(state) {
    const url = this.http.wsSession.concat('tableStateSave');
    const tableState = new TableState();
    tableState.idTable = TableState.convertIdStringTableToInt('customersTable');
    tableState.state = JSON.stringify(state);

    this.http.put(url, tableState, false).subscribe(
      () => null,
      (error: Response) => console.error(error)
    );
  }


  tableStateLoad(): any {
    return this.dataGridConfig;
  }
}
```

**MyComponent.html:**

```
<button (click)="create()" id="buttonCreate" class="btn btn-secondary rightFloat">Créer</button><br><br>
<button (click)="manualSave()" class="btn btn-secondary">Save state</button>

<dx-data-grid
    id="customersTable"
    [dataSource]="customersList"
    [allowColumnReordering]="true"
    [allowColumnResizing]="true"
    [columnAutoWidth]="true"
    [columnMinWidth]="50"
    [showBorders]="true"
    [rowAlternationEnabled]="true"
    [hoverStateEnabled]="true"
    (onRowRemoving)="delete($event.data)"
    (onRowClick)="view($event.data)"
>
    <dxo-column-chooser [enabled]="true"></dxo-column-chooser>
    <dxo-column-fixing [enabled]="true"></dxo-column-fixing>
    <dxo-search-panel [visible]="true" placeholder="Rechercher"></dxo-search-panel>
    <dxo-selection mode="single"></dxo-selection>

    <dxo-state-storing [enabled]="true" type="custom" savingTimeout="900000" [customSave]="tableStateSave" [customLoad]="tableStateLoad"></dxo-state-storing>

    <dxo-paging [pageSize]="10"></dxo-paging>
    <dxo-pager [showPageSizeSelector]="true" [allowedPageSizes]="[10, 20, 50, 100]" [showInfo]="true"></dxo-pager>
    <dxo-editing mode="row" [allowDeleting]="true"></dxo-editing>
    <dxo-export [enabled]="true" fileName="Mes clients"></dxo-export>
    <dxo-filter-row [visible]="true"></dxo-filter-row>
    <dxo-group-panel [visible]="true"></dxo-group-panel>
    <dxo-grouping #expand [autoExpandAll]="true"></dxo-grouping>

    <dxi-column dataField="id" caption="Id" [width]="30"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="name1" caption="Nom 1" [width]="150"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="name2" caption="Nom 2" [width]="150"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="email" caption="Email" [width]="300"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="dateCreated" caption="Date création" [width]="100" dataType="date" format="dd/MM/yyyy"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="dateUpdated" caption="Date modification" [width]="100" dataType="date" format="dd/MM/yyyy"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="state" caption="Etat" [width]="30" cellTemplate="cellTemplate_stateCustomer"></dxi-column>

    <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'cellTemplate_stateCustomer'">
        <span *ngIf="data.value == StateCustomer.BLOCKED">{{ Customer.getStateCustomer(StateCustomer.BLOCKED) }}</span>
        <span *ngIf="data.value == StateCustomer.ALLOWED">{{ Customer.getStateCustomer(StateCustomer.ALLOWED) }}</span>
    </div>
```

When running my test (spec file)

I god errors about the devExtreme syntax , i think that relative to my devExtreme module import , and generally any other library ,

My error is the following :

> Can't bind to 'dxTemplateOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
>   ("tate" caption="Etat" [width]="30"
>   cellTemplate="cellTemplate_stateCustomer">
>         ]*dxTemplate="let data of 'cellTemplate_stateCustomer'">
>             
>         [ERROR ->]
>             http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1690:21
>   <- src/test.ts:114544:34)
>         at TemplateParser.Array.concat.TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:12814:0
>   <- src/test.ts:125668:19)
>         at JitCompiler.Array.concat.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26966:0
>   <- src/test.ts:139820:39)
>         at http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26886:47
>   <- src/test.ts:139740:62
>         at Set.forEach (native)
>         at JitCompiler.Array.concat.JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26886:0
>   <- src/test.ts:139740:19)
>         at http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26787:0
>   <- src/test.ts:139641:19
>         at Object.then (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1679:32
>   <- src/test.ts:114533:148)
>         at JitCompiler.Array.concat.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents
>   (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26785:0
>   <- src/test.ts:139639:26)
>         at JitCompiler.Array.concat.JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync
>   (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26717:0
>   <- src/test.ts:139571:37)     Error: Template parse errors:   Can't bind
>   to 'dxTemplateOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("tate"
>   caption="Etat" [width]="30"
>   cellTemplate="cellTemplate_stateCustomer">
>         ]*dxTemplate="let data of 'cellTemplate_stateCustomer'">
>             
>         [ERROR ->]
>             http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1690:21
>   <- src/test.ts:114544:34)
>         at TemplateParser.Array.concat.TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:12814:0
>   <- src/test.ts:125668:19)
>         at JitCompiler.Array.concat.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26966:0
>   <- src/test.ts:139820:39)
>         at http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26886:47
>   <- src/test.ts:139740:62
>         at Set.forEach (native)
>         at JitCompiler.Array.concat.JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26886:0
>   <- src/test.ts:139740:19)
>         at http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26787:0
>   <- src/test.ts:139641:19
>         at Object.then (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1679:32
>   <- src/test.ts:114533:148)
>         at JitCompiler.Array.concat.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents
>   (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26785:0
>   <- src/test.ts:139639:26)
>         at JitCompiler.Array.concat.JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync
>   (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26709:0
>   <- src/test.ts:139563:42)     Expected undefined to be truthy.
>         at Object. (http://localhost:9877webpack:///src/app/customer/customers-list/customers-list.component.spec.ts:25:22
>   <- src/test.ts:232248:27)
>         at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:0 <-
>   src/polyfills.ts:1546:26)
>         at ProxyZoneSpec.Array.concat.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <-
>   src/test.ts:228722:39)
>         at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9877webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:0 <-
>   src/polyfills.ts:1545:32)

I need a general solution for such problems , because i think that i should find a way to import properly my modules to my test files similarly to my project components :

**Any suggestions ??**

Comment: Stub all components except the one that is tested, including third-party components, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396005/3731501.

Comment: @estus how may i do it , example of doin it may be great

Comment: It's described in the link above.