# Angular Karma Jasmine test "Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property"

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My Karma Jasmine tests of an Angular `@Component` complain that

> ERROR: 'Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'p'.'

When there is [that kind of error for the application itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331549/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tr-final-release), the [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40331563/545127) is to ensure you add `BrowserModule` to the `imports: []` in the `@NgModule()` of your application module (`app.module.ts`). I indeed have that import
(so this question is not a duplicate of that [canonical question about "Can't bind to 'ngXXX' since it isn't a known property of 'YYY'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331549/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tr-final-release)).

This is my test set-up code:

```
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                BrowserModule
            ],
            providers: [
                MyComponent,
                { provide: MyService, useClass: MockMyService }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        TestBed.inject(MyService);
        component = TestBed.inject(MyComponent);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

My HTML template says `*ngIf`, not `ngIf` or a typo for that, which is another [common cause of that error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47945655/545127):

```
<div class="self">
    <p *ngIf="isLoggedIn() else selfLogin">Logged in as
        {{getUsername()}}</p>
    <ng-template #selfLogin>
    <button id="login" (click)="login()">login</button>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

---

Putting the test module configuration and object injection in separate `beforeEach` calls (as suggested for a [different Angular testing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46919789/545127)) did not help.

Comment: Instead of `BrowserModule`, you need to import `CommonModule` I think but that import should not be need in tests. Are you sure you have `*ngIf="..."` and not `ngIf=".."` in your HTML? Also, try to add `compileComponents` after `configureTestingModule`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see you're including the Component in your `TestBed` `providers`. Components are normally part of `declarations`. So, something like this:

```
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
    let component: MyComponent;

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                { provide: MyService, useClass: MockMyService }
            ],
            declarations: [
                MyComponent
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.inject(MyService);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SelfComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

---

You also have a HTML formatting issue for your `else` declaration:

```
<div class="self">
    <p *ngIf="isLoggedIn() else selfLogin">Logged in as
        {{getUsername()}}</p>
    <ng-template #selfLogin>
    <button id="login" (click)="login()">login</button>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

should be...

`*ngIf="isLoggedIn(); else selfLogin"`

Comment: **Thanks** it works :) I just needed to add the `declarations` and the `compileComponents()` to solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error due to me not including the component-under-test in the declarations.

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
          MyComponent, // <-What i forgot.
          OtherComponent,
        ],
...
```